# JRPdfExporter is not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have createad a report in jasper report, when i have wrote the code in servlet to export the report in pdf it is not displaying the report.

```
JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
//OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
//pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "C:/reports/payment.pdf");
pdfExporter.exportReport();
```

Now during debugging when debugger came to at this line     JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter(); it simply goes in finally block rather in next line. I am stuck into this any solutions.

and the Exception is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
```

Comment: It would be great if you can provide exception message

Comment: there is no exception occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and It compiles and runs correctly. I suspect that problem is inside  `JasperPrint`. Make sure you actually complie a `JasperPrint` from your JRXML file.

If you set an empty `JasperPrint` into the `JRPdfExporter`, it will still runs correctly, but will result an empty PDF file.

Hope this help you locate the error.

### EDIT :

these Exception messages you provided are indicated that JVM can not locate `DocumentException`, according to package name, that's a class from iText library, if you have used iText, make sure you have included iText in your classpath.

Comment: JasperPrint object is returing correctly there is not an issue in JasperPrint because i am also using JRHtmlExporter and it is working fine. But i am facing the issue in this JRPdfExporter. I will have to re-look it again.

Comment: here is the exception...java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException

Comment: yeah sorry for late reply i also found the solution by importing iText jar file in class path and it works thanks Rangi.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not included "iText-2.1.7.js2.jar" file to your classpath. First include mentioned file then it will work fine.

Hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using maven just put your jasper dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and he put the dependency

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just include `itext-1.2.jar` inside your class path.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add http://itextpdf.com/ jar file